# RStudio Slidy presentation shows as a web page in browser

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, slidy

If from the RStudio menu, I select *File* > *New File* > *R Markdown ...*
and then select *Presentation*, *HTML (Slidy)*.

Leaving the sample code and pressing *Knit HTML*, opens the presentation in presentation mode in an RStudio browser (after saving).  However, if I then select *Open in Browser* the presentation shows as one page and pressing "a" to change to slide show mode does not work (tested with Chrome and IE)

This same behaviour does not occur if I choose HTML (ioslides), i.e. ioslides works as expected.

Is anyone else able to replicate this problem?  Any ideas?  Apparently javascript is enabled...

Comment: Please see https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/604

Comment: Great - thanks.  Updating from version 0.8.something to 0.9.2 fixed this.